# NPM missing building docker image for default dotnet angular project

Tags: .net, linux, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm trying to create basic Dockerfile for.NET 7 project which I created using `dotnet new angular`.

Build process is running on AWS CodeBuild but whatever I try, I get `npm: not found` or something similar.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential \
      nodejs
WORKDIR /src
COPY net7_test.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore "./net7_test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "net7_test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "net7_test.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "net7_test.dll"]
```

What am I missing? The structure of directory is default scaffolded project so Dockerfile and .csproj are on the same level.

EDIT:

It works using this lines instead of apt:

```
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
```

But it says that the script is deprecated.
So what is correct way of installing node and npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile installs Node's oldest version, and that bundle doesn't contain npm. All instructions on how to install Node for Debian are available on [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions).

Try this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base

ARG NODE_MAJOR

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg && \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install nodejs -y

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```